# Hashicorp Packer: ways to output a variable/local string value to a file

Tags: packer, hashicorp

I have some Packer templates which generate the content for configuration files which I then need to output to a configuration file. The end goal is to upload these files to the remote machine and then use the shell provisioner, but I can't seem to figure out the correct way of doing this. My current solution relies on a local shell provisioner to write the files, then I upload them to the remote, and then run the remote provisioner.

Something like,

```
locals {
  foo = "bar"
  foo_generated = templatefile("${path.root}/template-which-uses-foo.pkrtpl", foo)
}

provisioner "shell-local" {
  inline = [
    "cat >${path.root}/generated/foo.conf <<'STR'\n${local.foo_generated}"
  ]
}

provisioner "file" {
  source      = "${path.root}/generated/"
  destination = "/tmp/"
}

provisioner "shell" {
  inline = [
    "/tmp/do-something-with-foo-conf.sh",
  ]
}
```

While this works, the file generation looks very awkward, and I want to simplify it and make it more robust.

I initially started with defining `source`es for configuration file (there are many of them), in addition to the "base" ec2 source. However, from the logs it looked like Packer runs provisioners for each source inside of the build block, so it didn't seem like a good idea.

Are there better options to accomplish this?